# Applying boundary conditions to discretized hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, boundary-conditions, discrete

I am trying to implement reflecting boundary conditions of

$
\begin{align}
\psi_N \equiv \psi_{N-1},
\end{align}
$

$
\begin{align}
\psi_{-1} \equiv \psi_0,
\end{align}
$

to the hamiltonian matrix and then trying to find the 101 lowest energy eigen values. I am using a dimensionless schroedinger equation so $\hbar = 1$ and $m = \frac{1}{2}$ and also the potential $V = 0$.
How can I implement the boundary conditions to the square matrix? Here is the matrix and eigenvalue and eigenvector calculation without boundary conditions:

```
H = (dx**-2)*diags([-1, 2, -1], [-1, 0, 1], shape=(N, N))
eigval, eigvec = eigsh(H, 101, which="SM")
```

If there is any ambiguity in my question please let me know so I can make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably consider the following system of equations
$$
\frac1{dx^2}(2\psi_i - \psi_{i-1} - \psi_{i+1}) = E\psi_i,\quad \forall i = 0,\ldots, N-1, \quad (*)
$$
where, by definition, $\psi_N \equiv \psi_{N-1}$ and $\psi_{-1} = \psi_0$. There is no need to especially implement boundary conditions. Substitution of $\psi_N$ and $\psi_{-1}$ into equations $(*)$ gives a matrix slightly different from the matrix in your code.

According to the condition $\psi_{-1} = \psi_0$, you just need to rewrite the first equation
$$
\frac1{dx^2}(2\psi_0-\psi_{-1}-\psi_1) = E\psi_0
$$
in the following form
$$
\frac1{dx^2}(\psi_0-\psi_1) = E\psi_0.
$$
And you should rewrite the $N$-th equation in the same way.

Comment: You are correct, how will I have to modify the H matrix? I am aware the H[0,0] is psi_0 so where would psi_(-1) be in the H matrix ?  I was told that I must somehow alter the first and last row of the H matrix in order to implement the reflecting boundary conditions

Comment: @Σbaryon See the updated answer.

Comment: So I simply multiply the very first and very last terms in the H matrix by 0.5?

Comment: I hope you can write the right matrix for a system of linear equations.

Comment: Haha it seems to work I just wanted to clarify :)